# scaling the text size on the map when zooming in

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geojson

I'm trying to get an accurate adjustment of the text's font when I zoom in and zoom out of the map. everytime. This is the best I can do. Not sure how to accurately do it as this one is 1. very slow and laggy 2. when I zoom in the text gets bigger than the map.

I'm trying to understand how this one works

http://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/quick-tip-preserve-svg-text-size-after-scale-transform/

But i'm not sure where the scale or the font-size is getting set.

```
d3.json("../../json/mapped.json", function(json){
                var mapped = topojson.feature(json, json.objects.mapped);
                // projection
                var center = d3.geo.centroid(mapped);
                var scale = 100;

                var offset = [width/2, height/2];

projection.scale(scale).center(center).translate(offset);
                path.projection(projection);


var bounds = d3.geo.bounds(northluzon);
                var hscale = scale*width / (bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]);
                var vscale = scale*height / (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]);
                var scale = (hscale < vscale ) ? hscale : vscale;
                var offset = [width - (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0])/2,
                        height - (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1])/2];


projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                    .center(center)
                    .scale(scale)
                    .translate(offset);
                path = path.projection(projection);


svg.append("rect").attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
                    .style('stroke', 'black').style('fill', 'none');


g.selectAll("path")
                    .data(mapped.features)
                    .enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("d", path)
                    .attr('id', function(d){ 
                        return d.properties._id; } 
                    )
                    .on('mouseover', function(d){
                        $('#toolTip').fadeOut(100, function(){
                            $('#toolTipBody').html('tool tip test');
                            var popLeft = mousePos[0] + 20;
                            var popTop = mousePos[1] + 70;

                            $('#toolTip').css({ 'left': popLeft, 'top': popTop});
                            $('#toolTip').fadeIn(100);
                        });
                        d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'red');

                    })
                    .style("fill", "steelblue")
                    .style("stroke-width", "1")
                    .style("stroke", "black");


svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom()
                        .scale(projection.scale())
                        .translate(projection.translate())
                        .on('zoom', redraw));



gLabels = g.append('g').attr('id', 'labels')
                    .selectAll('text')
                    .data(mapped.features)
                    .enter()
                    .append('text')
                    .attr('x', function(d){ return path.centroid(d)[0]; })
                    .attr('y', function (d) { return path.centroid(d)[1]; })
                    .style('font-size', function(d){
                              return '6px';
                    })
                    .text(function(d){ return d.properties._id; });

redraw();
});


function redraw(){
                if(d3.event){
                    projection
                        .translate(d3.event.translate)
                        .scale(d3.event.scale);
                }

                svg.selectAll('path').attr('d', path);

                gLabels 
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return path.centroid(d)[0]; })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return path.centroid(d)[1]; })
                    .style('font-size', function(d){ 

                        var currSize = parseInt(getElementStyleValue(this.attributes, 'font-size'));
                        var newSize = Math.min(2 * currSize, (2 * currSize - 8)/ this.getComputedTextLength() * 12 ) + 'px';

                        return newSize;
                    });
            }
```